# Checkbox drawable with extra drawableLeft overlapping one another

Tags: android, checkbox, drawable, android-4.1-jelly-bean

When using a checkbox with extra drawable (besides the one used for the checkbox) using drawableLeft, the two drawables overlapp one another.

There is nothing special about the checkbox settings, here:

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/low_priority_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/low_priority"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_primary_priority_flag_low_medium"/>
```

Actual result:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

This problem occurs with compileSdkVersion 22 on devices with API <= 16

By the way, using drawableRight works as it should.

Is this a bug in the framework?
Any workaround?

Comment: Try width "fill parent"

Comment: @Halim android:layout_width="match_parent" doesn't solve the overlapping problem, but anyhow, I wouldn't want the checkbox width to be match_parent.

Comment: Yes the latest don't have this issue. I tried. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Add style (style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.CheckBox") for the checkbox, which can move the drawable to correct position. The only issue is the distance between drawable and text is bigger than normal case for devices with API <= 16.

One of my CheckBox xml is listed as the following:

```html
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/male_toilet_checkbox"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/m"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/m"
                android:text="@string/male_toilet"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#ff6c51ff"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/split_line1" />
```